# mysql query - insert data unix_timestamp ( now ( ) ) issue

Tags: mysql, unix, time, timestamp

I have an INT (11) column for storing the current timestamp in seconds. The query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO `abc` (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( NOW () ) )
```

I don't know why, but the date isn't changed. It doesn't matter when I send the query, the column value isn't changed. It has 1342692014 value, but I don't know why.

Is there any option or other function for timestamps? I must store dates in seconds.

Comment: 1342692014 = 2012-07-19 12:00:14 (CET), so looks like a correct value

Comment: you can also skip the `NOW()` part as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with no parameter gives the curent timestamp

Comment: Nope, it's not working. After the query, the timestamp it's only changed few seconds, than it start's from the beginning.

Comment: what date do you want to get? if you use NOW() you get todays date, and if you send the query a few secounds later your timestamp going to be a few secounds larger

Comment: date('d.m.Y - H:m:s', 1342693747) - This is how I convert the timestamp to date in php, but Why I always get the same minute 07 ? It goes to 12:07:00 - 12:07:59 than it start's from the beginning 12:07:00. It's like a cycle, it's always repeating it's self from 12:07:00 - 12:07:59. Why?

Comment: `date('m')` is month, use ´date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $)´

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You never refer to the `timestamp` **column** in your query. You only have a **string**:

```
INSERT INTO `abc` (id, 'timestamp') VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( NOW () ) )
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

**Edit:**

I get this with your updated code:

> ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION test.NOW does not exist. Check the
>   'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Assuming it's not still the actual code and after fixing the syntax error, I can't reproduce your results. My educated guess is that `id` is an auto-incremented integer primary key, your current SQL mode is making MySQL take `''` as `NULL` and inserting a new row... But I haven't really tested this hypothesis.

My working code is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
    `pk` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `timestamp` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO abc (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
-- Wait a few seconds
INSERT INTO abc (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
-- Wait a few seconds
INSERT INTO abc (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());

SELECT timestamp FROM abc WHERE id='';
```

... and returns this:

```
+------------+
| timestamp  |
+------------+
| 1342694445 |
| 1342694448 |
| 1342694450 |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you Alvaro for your effort. Yes, I forgot to mention that ID is an INT AUTO_INCREMENT FIELD. The UNIX_TIMESTAMP() it's working. The problem was caused when I tried to output the value from seconds to date in php. I used:

date('d.m.Y - H:m:s', $row['timestamp']);
and it should be:
date('d.m.Y - H:i:s', $row['timestamp']);

That caused all the bad thins.

Comment: A tip for the future: debug MySQL issues from MySQL :)

Comment: Its quite old post, but thought to update here...

There shouldn't be space between NOW and paranthesis (NOW ())

If there, it will throw 

_italic_#1630 - FUNCTION mydb.NOW does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual_italic_