# How to store number of seconds in database?

Tags: mysql, time

I want to store the number of seconds as a integer in the database. Something like this:

```
1451425369
```

But I cannot find a appropriate function to do that. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `CURTIME()`, `NOW()` and .. will store it like this:

```
2014-11-11 12:45:34
```

It should be noted, I don't access to something like PHP, because I want to do that using a `TRIGGER`. So I can't to use something like `time()`. Is there any idea?

Comment: Not sure what the number of seconds is in relation to? Either way, why not use a normal `int` field?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I use a normal `int(11)` data type, How should I fill it? I need to a MySQL-function to I write it in the query.

Comment: Just use int or long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1451425369 looks like a UNIX timestamp (2015-12-29 21:42 UTC). MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` field type stores as a UNIX timestamp under the hood, and you can retrieve that underlying timestamp value by doing something like:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field_name) FROM table_name;
```

If you need the current UNIX timestamp, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with no arguments will give you the current integer value. You can use this in an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` without issues.

Comment: My question is: How can I insert that UNIX timestamp in database?

Comment: @Shafizadeh You can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with no argument to fetch the current timestamp value. Something like `INSERT INTO table_name (field_name) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())` will insert it. You're usually better off using the `TIMESTAMP` field type and its more user-friendly data representation, though.

Comment: OH! I see. That's exactly what I needed :-) Thanks +1

Comment: And is there any specific reason about your suggestion except being user-friendly? *(using `TIMESTAMP` field type)*  Actually the whole of my website is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and I don't have time to change it ..! Anyway is there any particular reason ?

Comment: @Shafizadeh - the main reason is so that it is *readable*.  Otherwise, one has to convert it back and forth to figure out what date and time it represents.  It's also a good idea in general, as it will prevent it from being used with other functions that work with numbers that have nothing to do with time.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a MySQL database. If you want a Unix timestamp, like the first integer value you mentioned as an example, you can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. If you want the number of seconds of just today, starting with 0 at 12:00am, you could store `(HOUR(CURTIME())*60*60)+(MINUTE(CURTIME())*60)+SECOND(CURTIME())`.

```
INSERT INTO ttestsec(Sec) VALUES((HOUR(CURTIME())*60*60)+(MINUTE(CURTIME())*60)+SECOND(CURTIME()));
```

Comment: why not just the simpler time_to_sec(curtime())?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in [another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558418/mysql-query-insert-data-unix-timestamp-now-issue) Pasting the response below:

```
CREATE TABLE `abc` (
    `pk` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `timestamp` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO abc (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
-- Wait a few seconds
INSERT INTO abc (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
-- Wait a few seconds
INSERT INTO abc (id, timestamp) VALUES ('', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: Yea ..! This could be fine :-) +!