# Use UNIX_TIMESTAMP on update instead of timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a column with a unix timestamp to see when the row was last altered. So far i could only figure out how to add a column with timestamp format.

```
ALTER TABLE xyz.test ADD `insert_time` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Is there any solution to use a unix timestamp - something like this:

```
... INT ON UPDATE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() NOT NULL DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

**UPDATE:**

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558418/mysql-query-insert-data-unix-timestamp-now-issue)

As far as i understand this thread only shows how to add a unix timestamp manually to each row. I was wondering if it is also possible to do this automatically.

Comment: AFAIK mysql timestamp is already the same thing as  unix timestamp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql query - insert data unix\_timestamp ( now ( ) ) issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558418/mysql-query-insert-data-unix-timestamp-now-issue)

Comment: @LelioFaieta could you explain me what you mean by "is already the same thing as unix timestamp" - maybe i'm missing something fundamental here?

Comment: you can store a unix timestamp inside a timestamp type field in mysql. See the answer I mentioned in my other comment

Comment: @RandomDude `timestamp` stores integer value of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` but displays the value in human-readable format (`Y-m-d H:i:s`). Value of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is an integer. Value of `TIMESTAMP` column is that SAME integer, but it's displayed back in a format that you can read and understand. So, what exactly did you achieve?

Comment: @Mjh thanks for your explanation - i wasn't aware of that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TIMESTAMP` data type is the only one that supports the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default in MySQL. Internally the timestamp is stored as an int, but the interface uses a date time format.

You have some options to accomplish what you want:

**Store it as a timestamp, and apply the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function when you select from it**

```
select unix_timestamp(insert_time)
from xyz.test;
```

**Store it as an int, and use a trigger to populate the value**

```
ALTER TABLE xyz.test 
  ADD `insert_time_unix` INT NULL;

create trigger tr_b_ins_test before insert on xyz.test 
  for each row 
  set new.insert_time_unix = unix_timestamp(insert_time);

create trigger tr_b_upd_test before update on xyz.test 
  for each row 
  set new.insert_time_unix = unix_timestamp(insert_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for my CMS EFFCORE and I found it. Here is a 100% working example:

```
CREATE TABLE `demo` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `updated_at__on_insert`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `demo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END;;
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `updated_at__on_update`
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `demo`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET new.updated_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

p.s. None of the other solutions presented here describe everything accurately and clearly.